# illegal tag 0 when starting influxDB

Tags: influxdb

I have one issue when starting influxdb. The version is 1.5.2. Previously, it runs OK.

```
test@test-desktop:~$ sudo /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

 8888888           .d888 888                   8888888b.  888888b.
2018-07-05T02:34:53.494126Z info    InfluxDB starting   {"log_id": "0964WziW000", "version": "1.5.2", "branch": "1.5", "commit": "02d7d4f043b34ecb4e9b2dbec298c6f9450c2a32"}
2018-07-05T02:34:53.494316Z info    Go runtime  {"log_id": "0964WziW000", "version": "go1.9.2", "maxprocs": 2}
run: create server: proto: meta.Data: illegal tag 0 (wire type 0)
```

Any idea about this? Thanks